# Is Psalm 106:14-15 referring to general overall quasi-collective summarization of Israelites numerous quarrels with God Or is it more specific?

Tags: psalms, numbers, sin

I might be just asking the obvious or maybe I'm just being unnecessarily nit-picky but which plague among the Israelites is Psalm 106:14-15 discussing about?

The surrounding scripture verses (Psalm 106:16-18) refer to discipling Korah, Dathan and Abiram due to their actions in Numbers 16:1-40.
Based on the context of surrounding scripture verses (Psalm 106:16-18), it seems that Psalm 106:14-15 is discussing the events associated with Numbers 16:41-50 verses which is:

-Israelites grumbling due to the discipling of Korah, Dathan and Abiram

-and subsequent judgement & discipling from God in the form of the plague

> Psalm 106:11-18
>
> 11 The waters covered their adversaries; Not one of
> them was left. 12  Then they believed His words; They sang His praise.
> 13  They quickly forgot His works; They did not wait for His counsel,
> **14  But craved intensely in the wilderness, And [n]tempted God in the
> desert. 15  So He gave them their request, But sent a [o]wasting
> disease among them.**
> 16  When they became envious of Moses in the camp, And of Aaron, the
> holy one of the Lord, 17  The earth opened and swallowed up Dathan,
> And engulfed the [p]company of Abiram. 18  And a fire blazed up in
> their [q]company; The flame consumed the wicked.

However, the Psalm 106:14-15 verses do Not seem to exactly correlate with Numbers 16:41-50 because

a) Psalm 106:14 mentions the Israelites' craving intensely which does Not seem to correlate with Numbers 16:41 which mentions the Israelites' grumbling against Moses and Aaron regarding the discipling Korah, Dathan and Abiram due to their actions

b) Psalm 106:15 mentions that God affirmatively responded to their request, but for the Numbers 16:41-50 case, there is No request from the Israelites for anything

Therefore, would it be correct to say that Psalm 106:14-15 is just a general overall quasi-collective summarization of Israelites numerous quarrels with God and His appointed leaders, Moses and Aaron as mentioned in Exodus Numbers, etc.?

Or Is Psalm 106:14-15 specifically referring to Numbers 16:41-50's mentioning the Israelites' grumbling against Moses and Aaron regarding the discipling Korah, Dathan and Abiram due to their actions, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Psalm 106
New International Version

> 14In the desert they gave in to their **craving**;
> in the wilderness they put God to the test.
> 15So he gave them what they asked for,
> but sent a **wasting disease** among them.

a wasting disease
Strong's 7332: **Leanness**, wasting, scantness

They craved food. God fed them. In opposition, God also made them sick and scrawny. It was specific and served as a contrast.

God did similarly in Isaiah 10:

> 16Therefore, the Lord, the Lord Almighty,
> will send a **wasting disease** upon his **sturdy** warriors;
> under his pomp a fire will be kindled
> like a blazing flame.

God punished the strong Assyrian warriors by making them scrawny.

Answer (score 1):

KJV (or LEB) are better translations for the purpose of answering your question, because they do not try to medicalize the underlying MT:

רָזוֹן בְּנַפְשָׁם

rāzôn bənap̄šām

which just means "leanness in their [inner life/soul/life/throat]"

The word *nefesh* has a core concrete meaning of "throat/gullet" but in most situations the abstract meaning is intended, so it is translated as "inner life" or "life" and sometimes "soul". In the LXX it is translated as *psyche*.

Psalm 106:14–15 (KJV 1900)

> But lusted exceedingly in the wilderness,
> And tempted God in the desert.
> And he gave them their request;
> **But sent leanness into their soul.**

Psalm 106:14–15 (LEB)

> And they ⌊craved intensely⌋ in the wilderness,
> and tested God in the desert.
> So he gave to them their request,
> **but he sent leanness into their souls.**

One criticism of KJV and LEB is that in many cases where *nefesh* is translated as *soul*, it carries some metaphysical baggage -- e.g. the Hebrew *nefesh* need not be eternal or disembodied, and may be a reference to "inner self" instead. However there really isn't a better English word in many cases.

One *could* try to medicalize "leanness in the nefesh", but I would not advise translating the Bible this way as it requires playing doctor based on scant symptoms that are described in a book of poetry.

Bottom line, this could be purely a spiritual condition, a sense of lack and dissatisfaction represented as a hunger of the inner self, or it could be a throat problem.

I believe this is a reference to Numbers 11.4-6:

Numbers 11:4–6 (KJV 1900)

> And the mixt multitude that was among them fell a lusting: and the
> children of Israel also wept again, and said, Who shall give us flesh
> to eat?
>
> We remember the fish, which we did eat in Egypt freely; the
> cucumbers, and the melons, and the leeks, and the onions, and the
> garlick:
>
> But now **our soul is dried away**: there is nothing at all,
> beside this manna, before our eyes.

The bold clause in numbers is:
נַפְשֵׁ֥נוּ יְבֵשָׁ֖ה

nap̄šēnû yəḇēšâ

which means "our *nefesh* is dry". Thus this could be interpreted as "our soul is dry" or it could be interpreted as "our throat is dry", but from the context - *there is nothing at all, beside this manna, before our eyes* - what they clearly mean is that *they are sick of having nothing but manna in their throats*. Thus they have *a hunger for something new.*

In either case, the "leanness" or "lack in the throat" is a reference to Numbers 11.6.